# Prevent PHP from echoing if exception occured

Tags: php

I noticed that PHP's `echo` successfully prints strings even if somewhere in the script an error is thrown and not handled. For example:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

echo "started";
throw new Exception("big error");
echo "done";
```

prints `"started"`, even though an error occured. The status code is 500 indeed, but I don't think displaying partial results works for all cases.

Using `ob_start()` and `ob_get_contents()` offers some flexibility, but I expected that PHP offers a switch to set displaying to none if error occured. Does this switch exist?

Comment: Why would you expect the behaviour to be different?  Using `echo` prior to the exception would, of course, cause the content to be output.

Comment: Yeah, because php is a script language every line is executed in order.
And `echo` is a built-in function which immediately sends data to the client

Answer (score 2):

when you say throw new Exception() this means you are saying move the program control to caller and don't execute the further statements after this throw statement.

thanks to: [Difference between "throw new Exception" and "new Exception"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200662/difference-between-throw-new-exception-and-new-exception)

Comment: TS isnt asking why "done" isnt appearing, but why "started" does when he throws an exception (expection only the exception) :)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "started"; // <- This will occurs
throw new Exception("big error"); // <- And here the Exception will be thrown
echo "done"; // <- therefore, this line won't be reached
```

Comment: TS isnt asking why "done" isnt appearing, but why "started" does when he throws an exception (expection only the exception) :)

Comment: The "Exception" happens after  "started" line was `echoed`. 
One line after the other.

Answer (score 1):

Echo instantly send the data to the server (at least in this code it does) and no longer can be affected by what happens next. It's generally bad practice to work like that (eg: after an echo you can no longer change headers like a redirect, which can be very inconfinient), better would be to stored everything in a variable and output it when you want:

```
$output = "started";
throw new Exception("big error");
$output.= "done";

echo $output; // or if in a function, return instead of echo
```

Comment: Could you explain the statement _It's generally bad practice to work like that_ or cite some references that show it?

Comment: Hm, I tried to find some docs, but googling the words PHP and ECHO (no matter the words you add more) gives endless amounts of worthless results

Comment: I don't agree. Output buffering is not much different than what you are doing with the variables.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this would be using a variable to store what you want to echo and only echo it if there are no uncaught exceptions

```
$echoStr = "";

$echoStr .="started";

throw new Exception("big error");
$echoStr .="done";

echo $echoStr;
```

Comment: Hi Franscesco. While your answer is fine (it could use some explaining *why* the *current* solution doesnt work instead of only an answer), this has been answered a few times now :) Your answer adds no extra info. On SO we normally only add a new post if it adds something new. No intention to be harsh, but based on that logic, I recommend deleting this answer :)